# Interpreting an olympiad inequality as a convex function

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

We need to prove the following inequality:

> $$\frac{y^3xz}{x^3(xy+z^2)}+\frac{z^3xy}{y^3(x^2+yz)}+\frac{x^3yz}{z^3(xz+y^2)}\geq \frac{3}{2}$$

This equation is convex in each of the variables $x,y,z$. Moreover, its minimum seems to be at the origin (the equation is homogeneous, and there are not displacements of the vertex).

Can I then say that the minima is achieved when $x=y=z$? Clearly, when $x=y=z$, the value of the inequality is $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: It is equivalent to $$2 x^8 y^4 + 2 x^6 y^5 z + 2 x^7 y^3 z^2 - 3 x^5 y^5 z^2 - 
 3 x^6 y^3 z^3 + 2 x^5 y^4 z^3 - 3 x^3 y^6 z^3 + 2 x^2 y^7 z^3 - 
 6 x^4 y^4 z^4 + 2 x^3 y^5 z^4 + 2 y^8 z^4 - 3 x^5 y^2 z^5 + 
 2 x^4 y^3 z^5 - 3 x^2 y^5 z^5 + 2 x y^6 z^5 + 2 x^5 y z^6 - 
 3 x^3 y^3 z^6 + 2 x^3 y^2 z^7 + 2 x^4 z^8\geq0$$ which is true by Muirhead

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch- I don't know why I didn't do that. I am just scared of expanding everything out, as I'm scared of making a mistake. However, I think expanding everything and applying Muirhead should be a pretty safe bet in most situations

Comment: My method is definitely "ugly" in the sense that it is a bulldozer method (and prone to errors), but I like it a lot because it works so often and is so systematic (and when I am online I can do it with Mathematica in 3 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum\dfrac{y^3z}{x^2(xy+z^2)}\ge\dfrac{3}{2}$$
take 
$$a=\dfrac{x}{z},b=\dfrac{y}{x},c=\dfrac{z}{y}$$where $abc=1$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum \dfrac{b^2}{a+b}\ge \dfrac{3}{2}$$
use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$\sum\dfrac{b^2}{a+b}\ge\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum(a+b)}=\dfrac{a+b+c}{2}\ge\dfrac{3}{2}$$

Comment: I am aware of this method. I was wondering if my method also works

Answer (score 1):

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain: $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^3yz}{z^3(y^2+xz)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^4y^2}{z^2xy(y^2+xz)}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2y\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}z^2xy(y^2+xz)}=$$
$$=\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2y\right)^2}{xyz\sum\limits_{cyc}(y^2z+z^2x)}=\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2y\right)^2}{2xyz\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2y}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{z}\geq\frac{3}{2}.$$